# Build Perl to binary code stand alone

Tags: linux, perl, binaryfiles, ubuntu-10.04

How to build perl script in a bianry form ? and it is executable on i686 GNU/Linux

without any additional package or library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [perlbin](http://perlbin.sourceforge.net/perlbin-0.01.html)
- [pp](http://web.archive.org/web/20200927132707/https://www.perl.com/article/58/2014/1/5/The-easy-way-to-build-stand-alone-Perl-apps/)

Also see:

- [How does PAR::Packer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238420/how-does-parpacker-work)
- [The easy way to build stand-alone Perl apps](http://web.archive.org/web/20200927132707/https://www.perl.com/article/58/2014/1/5/The-easy-way-to-build-stand-alone-Perl-apps/)